# Weblogic and BOM

Tags: web-applications, weblogic, byte-order-mark, weblogic11g

We have web application with static content - html files, js files, images, etc.
**There are byte order mark at the beginning of all html files.**
These files were genereted by some tool. So I cannot modify them.
We deploy this application on Weblogic.
When I try to access this web application via direct link to Weblogic, then I have a lot of javascript errors.
But in case when I try to access this page via Apache proxy - then all is ok.
But Apache forwards all request direct to Weblogic.

And I do not have such errors in case if application was deployed on JBoss.
In this case I can access application both via direct link to JBoss and via proxy.

Anybody have some assumptions - why I cannot access application via direct link to Weblogic?

**SOLUTION:**
Add following mime mapping to web.xml:

```
   <mime-mapping>
      <extension>xml</extension>
      <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>

   <mime-mapping>
      <extension>js</extension>
      <mime-type>text/javascript</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
```

Comment: When you try direct access, it could be the relative path issue or some static content prefix which is messing up the JS files. Are the *view source when rendered via Apache* showing the same URL to the JS files as you see in *View source when rendered directly via Weblogic*

Comment: @VladimirBezugliy Please add your answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following mime mapping to web.xml:

```
   <mime-mapping>
      <extension>xml</extension>
      <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>

   <mime-mapping>
      <extension>js</extension>
      <mime-type>text/javascript</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
```